# E492 : not an editor command:TlistToggle

Tags: vim, taglist, vundle

I met this error when I install taglist in vim.But I have already installed taglis.**What should I settle this problem**?
The follows are my configuration files：

.vimrc:

```
Plugin 'Valloric/ListToggle'
```

I used the command (`:BundleInstall`)to install the taglist.

And in the file :`~/.vim/bundle`
ListToggle file exsits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used that plugin so I am not sure about the situation, but are you sure the plugin you've installed is correct?

- [Valloric/ListToggle](https://github.com/Valloric/ListToggle/blob/master/plugin/listtoggle.vim) doesn't seem to ship any command named `TlistToggle`, hence the error.
- After a quick search, a plugin called [taglist (on vim.org)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) exports `TlistToggle`. Maybe this is the plugin you intend to install?